# Way to access from a repository to two values in session - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session, repository

i has in the Session two values:

> classroom and subject

I update this values with Handlers in my web, and i use in multiple controllers, but i have a problem?

I call one EntityRepository and use a various functions multiple times, with the same two values: classroom and subject, so I decided to modify the constructor of the EntityRepository:

```
class StudentRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    function __construct($em, ClassMetadata $class) {

      parent::__construct($em, $class);
      $this->classroom = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('classroom');
      $this->subject = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('subject');
    }
....
```

But, obvius, not work because i cant access to the Session in a EntityRepository, and i think put this 2 values in every function of this ER its really a shit, so, Any option?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered DI (deferred) the session? You can add the following to your service:

```
student_repository_Service:
...
calls:
    - [setSession, ["@session"]]
```

Then, creating the `setSession` method, storing the session in a variable, and you could access the session from `$this->session`...